# Android Change View After Certain Amount of Time

Tags: java, android, android-studio, oncreate

I'm new to AndroidStudio and am having trouble finding a way to change views without requiring action from the user. More specifically, I'm trying to make my app display a title screen when it opens, then switch to the main interface after a few seconds. I found this code for changing views from the current view to the DisplayMessageActivity class in the android tutorials:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I tried to use this code in my onCreate method of my title screen Activity as such:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.title_screen);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then I set up the second view in the new Activity. I also tried to just use two separate views in the onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.title_screen);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
}
```

However, in both cases, it only displays the second view. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using same layout in both activities, fix that (R.layout.....)

Avoid Thread.sleep as it will block the app itself.
you have to introduce delay when calling the second activity. pls refer
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCLO7q2uhOs

Your following code should be put in a handler block with the time delay you want

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Look that both onCreate methods are from the same Activity (but two options that he do to prove it).

Answer (score 0):

Here: `Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);`

The problem it's that you are sending your `Intent` to the same class in both cases (`DisplayMessageActivity.class`). You have to change, in your `onCreate` method, the class in which the Intent is going to being sent (the second view).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, **The class in which you are going to show your second view**);
```

I expect it will be useful for you!